# How long is this part of the Boeing 737 and cockpit?

Tags: cockpit, tail

[image] I can never find information for the length of each of these areas. For the cockpit length is the nose to the bathroom and the back of the airplane is the coffee symbol to the tail of the aircraft.

Comment: Gotta ask: what do you need such obscure dimensions for?

Comment: I typed "boeing 737 dimensions" into google and quickly found https://www.flickr.com/photos/wbaiv/sets/72157622773807476/, among other things.

Comment: @Airsick My goal is to design an aircraft that will change the future of flight. Almost all of my questions have had something related to the design. I want to know the dimensions to know how big to make the tail and cockpit of the aircraft.

Comment: @GregHewgill That's weird I have typed in boeing 737 dimensions and never found this information on google.

Comment: With respect, @Ethan, I don't think you're going to change much by copying arbitrary dimensions from a B737.

Comment: @Airsick I know but I want to get the basic idea of the lengths for the tail and the cockpit.

Comment: You already have a scale drawing. Wikipedia tells you the total length of the plane. Your profile says you're 14 years old. By the time I was that age, my school maths syllabus had definitely included how to use ratios, which are enough to calculate any dimension from a scale drawing where you know one of the dimensions. If you don't know even that basic mathematics then I'm sorry but you're unlikely to be able to design any working aircraft, let alone one that will "change the future of flight".

Comment: @DavidRicherby I know, but I want to come up with the concept at my age. Then when I get older and learn more mathematics I could then fully design the aircraft. You would be surprised about my design and how complicated and complex it is( and maybe it will change the future of flight I have some ideas that are new)

Comment: I would venture to say that the specified portion of the aircraft is exactly as large as it needs to be to contain the items that need to be there. Any smaller and the cockpit related items (seats, controls, monitors, electronics, etc) wouldn't fit. Any larger and the designers are wasting space that could be used for fare-paying pax. I would suggest that your revolutionary design use this methodology, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working from the scale images in the Boeing [Aircraft Characteristics for Airport Planning](http://www.boeing.com/assets/pdf/commercial/airports/acaps/737.pdf) document:

All the 737 models are covered, but as an example, for a 737-800 we see this drawing giving general dimensions:

[image]

The scale is given at the foot of the document: 4m per square.

From your illustration the forward dimension looks to be about the first two squares, i.e. 8m, or 26ft 3in, approximately.

Similarly the rear dimension is about 2.5 squares, or 10m (32ft 10in.)

Comment: Is the length the same for the 700 version?

Comment: I've given you the link for the document, which has similar diagrams for all the 737 models. You should be able to get almost any dimension you want from there.